# File name changes after opening downloaded excel file in .Net C# MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, excel, asp.net-mvc-4, export-to-excel

I am trying to export data as Excel in my C#.Net MVC Application. I have used `return file()` in `Actionresult`. The file is returned and downloaded successfully.

But there is error while opening file and the file names gets changed when it is opened.
Downloaded file name is `ExportFilterCRMdoctorRequest.xls` but after opening it changes to `Book1`.
code for Exporting file:

```
public ActionResult ExportFilterCRMdoctorRequest() 
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<CDRFilterCRMDoctorRequest>));

            //We load the data
            List<CDRFilterCRMDoctorRequest> data = (List<CDRFilterCRMDoctorRequest>)Session["filterCRMRequestList"]; //Retriving data from Session

            //We turn it into an XML and save it in the memory
            serializer.Serialize(stream, data);
            stream.Position = 0;

            //We return the XML from the memory as a .xls file
            return File(stream, "application/vnd.ms-excel", "ExportFilterCRMdoctorRequest.xls");
        }
```

[image]

[image]

[image: The file name got changed to "Book1"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called **Extension Hardening**. Execute steps to avoid this error.

> 1. Open your Registry (Start -> Run -> regedit.exe) Navigate to
> 2. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\OFFICE\12.0\EXCEL\SECURITY
> 3. Right click in the right window and choose New -> DWORD Type
> 4. “ExtensionHardening” as the name (without the quotes)
> 5. Verify that the data has the value “0″

### **NOTE**

> There is one thing that has to be borne in mind when serializing in
>   XML. XML is not Excel’s standard format and it has to open the file as
>   XML data. This means that when opening the file it will issue a couple
>   of warnings which are more of a nuisance than anything else.

### **Back to your original Query : Replicated your issue and below is the fix**

### **Sample Class**

```
public class StudentModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Class { get; set; }
    public string Section { get; set; }
}
```

### **Sample Data**

```
private List<StudentModel> StudentData()
{
    List<StudentModel> objstudentmodel = new List<StudentModel>();
    objstudentmodel.Add(new StudentModel { Name = "Name1", Class = "1", 
                                         Address = "Address1", Section = "A" });
    objstudentmodel.Add(new StudentModel { Name = "Name2", Class = "2", 
                                         Address = "Address2", Section = "A" });
    return objstudentmodel;
}
```

### **Action Method**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<StudentModel> objstudent = new List<StudentModel>();
    objstudent = StudentData();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<table border='" + "1px" + "'b>");
    //code section for creating header column
    sb.Append("<tr>");
    sb.Append("<td><b><font size=2>NAME</font></b></td>");
    sb.Append("<td><b><font size=2>CLASS</font></b></td>");
    sb.Append("<td><b><font size=2>ADDRESS</font></b></td>");
    sb.Append("<td><b><font size=2>SECTION</font></b></td>");
    sb.Append("</tr>");

    //code for creating excel data
    foreach (StudentModel item in objstudent)
    {
        sb.Append("<tr>");
        sb.Append("<td><font>" + item.Name.ToString() + "</font></td>");
        sb.Append("<td><font>" + item.Class.ToString() + "</font></td>");
        sb.Append("<td><font>" + item.Address.ToString() + "</font></td>");
        sb.Append("<td><font>" + item.Section.ToString() + "</font></td>");
        sb.Append("</tr>");
    }
    sb.Append("</table>");
    HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", 
                                   "attachment; filename=student_" + 
                                   DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + ".xls");
    this.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

    byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
    return File(buffer, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer... it Solved the Error n Warning problem. I want to ask a thing is it possible to return file as .xlsx? Nowadays mostly we use Excel 2007 or higher.